# Preventing startx after login on my Raspberry pi

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to set up my pi to operate through SSH in anticipation of a robot project. I've successfully set up a SSH client on my laptop (PuTTY) and enabled SSH using raspi-config. I can login to the pi via SSH but the screen, having displayed the login progress becomes unresponsive, whatever I type in is ignored. There is only a 'block' cursor and no raspverrypi 'prompt' visible.

On conncting the pi to a screen I see that LXDE has started. I assume this is my uderlying problem. How do I prevent startx from running automatically on login?

Comment: Which distribution are you using? There is a separate raspberrypi stackexchange that might be more useful (http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). Check the user .profile script and /etc/profile or ~/.bashrc to ensure that is not launching X for you.

Comment: Not sure how to identify 'distribution'. Naiive pi user. Tried all the options you suggested to no avail. I assume I should be looking for startx. However. in trying to copy the startup text the screen jumped to life with the following :                                                   ^Cxinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

xinit: unexpected signal 2
pi@raspberrypi:~$
and I'm away! Will use ^C as a w'workaround' for now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using raspbian you can simply run `sudo raspi-config` to disable starting the X server after boot.

More answers are listed here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/boot-without-starting-x-server